# Disable mouse in application switcher

Tags: 18.04, mouse, application-switcher, 19.04

I am using the default application switcher in an out-of-the-box Ubuntu 19.04.

My mouse has a hardware problem that makes it moves a tiny bit every two seconds or so, and it is integrated in my rare laptop so replacement parts are impossible to find. Using an external mouse is not an option.

I use the keyboard for almost everything except web browsing, and my mouse usually sits idle in the middle of the screen.

**PROBLEM**: I press CTRL-TAB, press TAB again until the cursor is on the right application, then release the CTRL key... and the mouse decided to move just at the wrong time, and unfortunately just moving the mouse over the application switcher changes the selection, so the wrong application comes up.

I never press CTRL-TAB then select the right app with the mouse, so I want to disable the mouse in the application switcher. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, it happens so often to me in a day and is annoying.

Comment: @alpipego No solution yet unfortunately, it still bugs me several times per day. Best part is when I intend to show a demo to a customer and the mouse decides to show some confidential memo or company chat window instead :-/

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution. This seems to have become a problem in 18, as I didn't have this problem in Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Just stopping by here in August 2022 to report the same annoying problem in Ubuntu 22.04...